# Propel & Sympfony 2 Autoloader

Tags: php, symfony, include, propel

I am currently using Propel 1.6 and Symfony 2 autoloader class.

My problem is that I can access the first class but it somehow doesnt access the other classes
The error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'model\om\BaseUser' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gym\build\classes\model\User.php on line 20
```

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="gym" namespace="model" defaultIdMethod="native">
```

The build.properties

```
# Database driver
propel.database = mysql

# Project name
propel.project = gym
propel.namespace.autoPackage = true
propel.database.url = mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test
propel.database.user = root
propel.database.password =
```

The PHP

```
// Include the main Propel script
require_once '/propel/Propel.php';
// Initialize Propel with the runtime configuration
//Propel::init("/build/conf/gym-conf.php");

require_once realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . "/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php";
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();

$loader->registerNamespaces( array ( 
                                    "build\classes\model" => realpath( dirname( __FILE__ )  ),
                                    "Symfony\Component" => realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ),
                                    "s" => __DIR__
                        ));


$loader->register();

use \build\classes\model\User;
$a = new User;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a classic autoloading issue... register your namespace with the autoloader correctly.

Make sure you have registered **model\om** with it's real path in your autoloader if it uses a *different* path than the other namespaces.

```
$loader->registerNamespaces( array ( 
    // ... namespaces here 
    "model\om" =>  'path_here',
));
```

If that's not the solution you might have a missing/wrong use-statement in your \build\classes\model\User...

... or you are trying to construct an inexistant class like this.

```
// this tries to load BaseUser build\classes\model\model\om\BaseUser
// ... if used in User.php
$baseUser = new model\om\BaseUser;
```

... when it should instead read

```
$baseuser = new \model\om\BaseUser;
```

... or better

```
use model\om\BaseUser;

// ...

$baseUser = new BaseUser();
```

... or your BaseUser class violates **PSR** naming conventions in some way.